# How to do y-split for tree nodes in pstree?

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

As I need to draw [lines between edges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74043/create-line-between-two-edges-in-pstree), I'd like to have y-splits when there are multiple child nodes. At the moment I realized it through a hidden node and `nodesep=0`. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to reset `nodesep` for the direct parent and children of the split node and therefore the spacings are wrong (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\newcommand{\terminal}[2][]{\TR[#1]{\boldsymbol{#2}}}
\newcommand{\nonterminal}[2][]{\TR[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\emptyword}{\TR{\epsilon}}
\newcommand{\derivationtree}[1]
{
    \begin{postscript}
        $   \pstree[treemode=R,nodesep=2pt,treesep=0.4cm,levelsep=1.5cm]{\TR{S}}{#1} $
    \end{postscript}    
}

\begin{document}

\derivationtree{
  \pstree[nodesep=0]{\nonterminal{N_1}}
  {
    \pstree{\Tr{}}
    {
        \pstree[nodesep=2pt]{\nonterminal{N_1}}
        {
            \terminal{[}
        }
        \terminal{[}
    }
  }
}

\end{document}
```

In the pst-tree manual, there is an example where `\psedge` is redefined as `\ncdiag`. But I couldn't really figure out how to do it and how to restrict the effects just for one case.

Comment: and between which nodes should the line be drawn?

Comment: that doesn't matter here, it should be exactly as in the screenshot but with right spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one redefines `\psedge` but it works with any other definition.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\newcommand\terminal[2][]{\TR[#1]{\boldsymbol{#2}}}
\newcommand\nonterminal[2][]{\TR[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\emptyword{\TR{\epsilon}}

\def\psEdge#1#2{\ncdiagg[armA=1cm,angleA=0,angleB=180]{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\derivationtree[1]{
    \begin{postscript}
        $   \pstree[treemode=R,nodesep=2pt,treesep=0.4cm,levelsep=1.5cm]{\TR{S}}{#1} $
    \end{postscript}}

\begin{document}

\derivationtree{%
  \pstree[thislevelsep=2.75cm]{\nonterminal{N_1}}{
        \pstree{\nonterminal[edge=\psEdge]{N_1}}{ \terminal{[} }
        \terminal[edge=\psEdge]{[}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, looks good! Now the only remaining problem is that the split introduces vertical level spacing (see http://i48.tinypic.com/282g5fm.png) which I didn't have before. It might not be a standard case, but still... (I wouldn't care, but it doesn't fit on my slide anymore :D)

Comment: sure that is the default for existing child nodes. Use a fixed value for `treesep` if you do not like it (or `thistreesep`)

Comment: Hm but don't I already use a fixed `treesep`? See my definition for `\derivationtree`

Comment: I cannot see it in my example

Comment: See http://pastie.org/4798814 vs http://pastie.org/4798820

Comment: I see, the vertical distance of `\psdiagg` is taken into account. There is no quick solution, must dig into the sources.

Comment: use `\pstree[levelsep=1cm]{\TR{S}}{\emptyword}\tspace{-10pt}% ` I don't know why it is not done by default. However, with `\tspace{...}` you can correct it.

Comment: That's it, perfect! Thanks for your help, I really appreciate your effort :)